# why (miniconda) pip install in .local

Tags: python-3.x, pip, miniconda

`pip install` is installing packages in my user's `.local` directory, a behaviour that I would like to avoid. Here is my setup:

```
(base) MYUSER@MYMACHINE:~$ which pip
/home/MYUSER/miniconda3/bin/pip

(base) MYUSER@MYMACHINE:~$ which python
/home/MYUSER/miniconda3/bin/python
```

An example trying to install `bottleneck`:

```
(base) MYUSER@MYMACHINE:~$ pip install bottleneck -v
...
Installing collected packages: numpy, bottleneck


  changing mode of /home/MYUSER/.local/bin/f2py to 775
  changing mode of /home/MYUSER/.local/bin/f2py3 to 775
  changing mode of /home/MYUSER/.local/bin/f2py3.6 to 775

Successfully installed bottleneck-1.3.2 numpy-1.19.0
Cleaning up...
```

Although I expect `bottlneck` to be installed in `/home/MYUSER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages`, it actually gets installed in `.local` instead:

```
(base) MYUSER@MYMACHINE:~$ ls ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bottleneck/
benchmark                             nonreduce_axis.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  _pytesttester.py                        src
__init__.py                           nonreduce.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so       reduce.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  tests
move.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  __pycache__                                     slow                                    _version.py
```

I hope I have provided enough information to debug this.

Comment: What is the output of `pip config list`? I wonder if you set some options for `pip` globally at some point in the past that it is using.

Comment: No output from `pip config list`. But I think I know what the issue is. I'll answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crucial piece of information that I thought was irrelevant is that I am executing these commands in a `VNC` session. It was brought to my attention that the environment variables when a new terminal is launched within the `VNC` session are inherited from the terminal that created the `VNC` session.

For more information:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400329/gnome-terminal-inherits-some-environment-even-with-env-i-on-a-vnc-session

In my case, the environment variables (i.e. PATH, PYTHONPATH) were messed up due to the above reason. Solved now